# Should we change the [altera] tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Altera was acquired by Intel and now it is mostly marketed as *Intel FPGA*. The [decision](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/which-tags-should-be-used-for-intel-fpgas) on EE.SE was to create [intel-fpga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-fpga) tag and make [altera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/altera) a synonym of it.

A change would be nice for Stack Overflow too, whether similar or different.